# Solr Range Facets dynamically modifying the ranges based on the search query

Tags: apache, solr, solrj

So here is what I am trying to do.
I have a facet defined on the price field.

1) When there is a query for "wordA"
I want the facets to be from 0-1000 divided in 5 intervals since my maximum price for "wordA" will never exceed 1000

2) When there is a query for "wordB"
I want the facets to be from 0-50 divided in 5 intervals since my maximum price for the query "wordB" will never exceed 50.

So basically I want the facet range to change dynamically so that I don't end up with a range of 0-1000 for a query "wordB" where all the hits will lie in the 1st range.

If solr does not support this then it will be a lot of query post processing involved to modify the ranges based on the returned results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr does not support that, but you can do it yourself by doing two queries - first [get the stats (max, min)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component) for the field, then submit a query for the [facet ranges (intervals)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-IntervalFaceting) that are suitable for your application.