# Dynamic facet limits using Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, facet, faceted-search

How can I group my Solr query results using a numeric field into x buckets, where the bucket start and end values are determined when the query is run?

For example, if I want to count and group documents into 5 buckets by a wordCount field, the results should be:

250-500 words: 3438 results
500-750 words: 4554 results
750-1000 words: 9854 results
1000-1250 words: 3439 results
1250-1500 words: 38 results

Solr's faceting API docs assume that the facet buckets are known in advance, but this isn't possible for numeric fields because the lower and upper buckets depend on the search results.

My current query (which doesn't work) is:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/pages/query -d '
q=*:*&
rows=0&
json.facet={
  wordCount : {
    type: range,
    field : wordCount,
    start : max(wordCount),
    end : min(wordCount),
    gap : 1000
  }
}'
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179596/solr-range-facets-dynamically-modifying-the-ranges-based-on-the-search-query), which suggests calculating the buckets in the application code prior to sending them to Solr for counting. This is not ideal because it involves querying the database multiple times, and also the answer is several years out of date and since then Solr has added the JSON faceting API, which allows more complicated faceting settings.

In SQL, this type of dynamic bucketing is possible with union queries, in which each query in the union which calculates a specific bucket's lower and upper bounds and counts the results in that bucket. So it seems weird that in Solr, where a lot of effort has gone into making faceting easy, this kind of query is not possible.

Comment: Do you want the end result to always have a static number of buckets? How do you want the interval to be determined in that case? (i.e. the `1000` value in your example) I'm also guessing your min/max values should be swapped around? (start => min, end => max)

Comment: @MatsLindh                                                                                                       
1. Yes I would want 10 buckets.(in order to calculate  that we would need the max and min field)
2. The interval would be calculated based on the max(wordcount) / 10
3. Yes I suppose they should be swappable 

Thank you for responding